# Apache Nutch avoid refetching

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

I'm crawling a couple of websites with Apache Nutch, but I've noticed that at each iteration the 95% of the websites that it crawls, are already in the database. 
I'm using the script crawl in the bin directory, with batches of 50k urls.

I was wondering if I could avoid the refetching of the urls that I've already in the database in someways.

Answer (score 0):

With the default settings, the URLs should be refetched every 30 days only [db.fetch.interval.default](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/conf/nutch-default.xml#L416). you could increase this value as well as the one *db.fetch.interval.max*. URLs are always refetched by Nutch even when they are marked as GONE.

**EDIT** Your problem could also be that a few hostnames are over represented in the segments and that as a result you don't discover and crawl URLs from other sources. If so edit [generate.max.count](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/conf/nutch-default.xml#L715) and [generate.count.mode](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/master/conf/nutch-default.xml#L724)

Comment: The value is setted at the default value, so as you state, it should be fetched each 30 days. I have only a limited list of 3000 websites from which it can fetch. Could it possibly affect my crawling?

Comment: @rodi not sure I understand what the issue is. If you want to not refetch URLs you already fetched then change the db.fetch.interval configs as explained. I updated the answer with a possible explanation can you clarify what you mean?